# Multi language: asp:label aganist html:label with asp:Literal

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm adding multi language support to a prototype web site. The site was developed using html lables which I could multilanguage using asp:literal or I could change them all to asp:labels as shown below.

```
<asp:label ID="lblAddress1" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources:lblAddress1 %>' /></br> 

<label><asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:lblAddress1 %>"></asp:Literal></label>
```

Web stuff isn't my area of expertise and the guys here don't think there is any advantage one way or the other. What would you choose and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a matter of taste. Although I think the second option may add a little weight to the page because literals are usually wrapped in `<span`>

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:Literal>
```

Use this control as a placeholder for any text you wish to insert in the page. The output will not be wrapped in any html markup tags (simplest).

```
<asp:Label>
```

Use this control in the same way as the , however, This control will wrap the text in html  tags. These span tags allow the  control to have additional properties (css styling etc.) which can be leveraged.

```
<label>
```

This html tag has semantic value in a page and is used to associate form elements with their description.

```
<label for="SaveLoginName">Remember Me:</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="SaveLoginName" />
```

A browser can use this info to provide additional accessibility  features such as  enabling clicking  text to toggle checkbox value.

Each of these have appropriate usage scenarios.